# Tkinter argument passing to handler via private attributes - is this OK?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have seen several solutions for passing additional arguments to a Tkinter event handler that use wrapper functions in different ways.  But for a simple case of passing some extra static data in the event is there any drawback to doing it this way:

widget.my_private_attribute = my_private_data

and recovering the data from the event in the event handler:

private_data = event.widget.my_private_attribute

I've tried it and it works, but it doesn't appear in any of the suggested solutions I've seen so I'm concerned there's some drawback I'm not aware of.

Here is a code sample.  Re the comment on the meaning of "private" I guess that was misleading.  I meant "made up by me, not one of the standard tk attributes".

```
:
:
def onClickPosition(event):
    print "you clicked on", event.widget.grid_position
    if event.widget.cget("bg") == "red":
        event.widget.config(bg="yellow")
    else:
        event.widget.config(bg="red")

root = tk.Tk()

buttonList = []

for i in range(16):
    for j in range(16):
        square = tk.PhotoImage(file="small_square_30x30pix.gif")
        l = tk.Label(root, image=square, borderwidth=0, bg="yellow")
        l.save_image = square
        l.grid_position=(i,j)
        l.bind("<1>", onClickPosition)
        l.grid(row=i, column=j)
        buttonList.append(l)
:
:
```

"grid_position" is the data I an referring to.

I've seen several variations on the solution at:

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/extra-args.html

But the way I'm doing it seems simpler.

Comment: "Private"? What do you mean, "private"? Regardless, I would store the data where it makes sense to store it. If it doesn't help form the widget, it shouldn't be an attribute of the widget. Post a small code sample to describe the issue and how you're dealing with it.

Comment: Sorry about the bad formatting of the code, this is my first time here and I'm struggling with the editor

Comment: ahh.... fixed now I think

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
l.grid_position=(i,j)
l.bind("<1>", onClickPosition)

...

def onClickPosition(event):
    print "you clicked on", event.widget.grid_position
```

try:

```
l.bind("<1>", lambda event, i=i, j=j: onClickPosition(event, i, j))

...

def onClickPosition(event, i, j):
    print "you clicked on", (i,j)
```

`lambda` defines an inline anonymous function, allowing us to send more arguments to `onClickPosition()`. Putting `i=i, j=j` in the definition makes those variables resolve when the function is defined instead of when it's called - `lambda event, i, j` will always produce a click position of `(15, 15)`.

Answer (score 1):

It the value "belongs to" the widget in any meaningful sense, then yes, not only is it safe to attach it as an attribute, it's idiomatic.

There are plenty of examples in the documentation.

For one thing, every example that uses the "standard Tkinter OO idiom" of subclassing `Frame` to add attributes in the `__init__` method or elsewhere is doing exactly what you're doing. The fact that you don't have a subclass isn't relevant; it's the same idea.

If you don't buy that, see the Tkinter Book's [`PhotoImage`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) page:

> Note: When a PhotoImage object is garbage-collected by Python (e.g. when you return from a function which stored an image in a local variable), the image is cleared even if it’s being displayed by a Tkinter widget.
>
> To avoid this, the program must keep an extra reference to the image object. A simple way to do this is to assign the image to a widget attribute, like this:

```
label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack()
```

`label` isn't a subclass of `Label` that has another attribute named `image`, it's just a `Label`, and we've just added another attribute dynamically, and that's perfectly fine.

And this was just the first example I found in a few seconds of skimming.

---

But it's *also* perfectly fine to "partial" the value into the callback itself, as in [TigerhawkT3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30407605/908494)'s answer.<sup>*</sup>

<sub>* In fact, I believe that was one of the arguments that convinced Guido that Python 3.x still needs both `lambda` and `partial`.</sub>

---

So, how do you decide which one to use? It's a judgment call. Here's how I'd think about it:

- Is the value naturally a member of the widget, or is that kind of a stretch?
- Are you already using a widget subclass?
- Do you have multiple callbacks that all need to access the same value?
- Is it conceivable that you'd have some other use for the value (e.g., in debugging output), or does that make no sense?

<sub>If none of those help, well, you eventually need some default strategy for handling close judgment calls. I like to write it both ways and then see which one looks more readable, or imagine explaining both to a novice who just signed up to help me maintain the code. And if I still can't decide, I type `random.random() < 0.5` into the interactive interpreter. :)</sub>